# Double passive: "required to be registered", "proposed to be left out", "omitted to be done"

Tags: adjectives, passive-voice, past-participles

> A few double passives are defensible—e.g.:
>
> > “Offerings in compliance with Regulation D are not **required to be
> > registered** with the SEC under the Securities Act.”
>
> As Ernest Gowers (FMEU2 at 139) noted: “In legal or quasi-legal language this construction may sometimes
> unexceptionable:
>
> > Diplomatic privilege applies only to such things as are done or
> > **omitted to be done** in the course of a person’s official duties.
>
> > Motion made: that the words **proposed to be left out** stand part of the
> > Question”
>
> But these are of a different kind from **are sought to be included**
> and **are attempted to be refuted**, which can be easily remedied by
> recasting. The principle is that if the first passive-voice
> construction can be made active—leaving the passive infinitive
> intact—the sentence is correctly formed.

Why aren't here [registered](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/registered#Adjective) or [left out](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/left_out#Adjective) adjectives instead?

Secondly, why is the verb [omit](https://oed.com/oed2/00045924) accepted when it doesn't work with [said "principle", for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice#Double_passives)

> ACTIVE: Expect/＊omit somebody to do something
>
> PASSIVE: Something is expected/＊omitted to be done (by somebody)

Comment: *I expected to mention this* and *I omitted to mention that* are both perfectly idiomatic, but with *I expected to see this / I omitted to see that*, the "omit" version is at the very least "unusual". And if there's an "embedded subject" in the infinitival clause, as in *I expected **you** to say this*, the corresponding "omit" version *I omitted **you** to say that* is just completely invalid. That's because [the two verbs have different syntactic affordances.](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/40258/does-every-semantic-ambiguity-produce-an-equivalent-syntactic-ambiguity)

Comment: @FumbleFingers "_Recently I heard it suggested by a friend that too many books appear with endnotes_. Grammatically speaking, that sentence contains the implied verb **being** after  _it_, so it’s in the passive voice. To make it active: _Recently I heard a friend suggest that too many books appear with endnotes_." Then, should it not have benn **be** in its passive, instead of the present participle?

Comment: I've got no problem with [*Never again will I stand by in silence and **watch you be attacked**.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22watch+you+be+attacked%22) But I'm also fine with [*It nearly killed me to **watch you being attacked***.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22watch+you+being+attacked%22) AND I'm fine with [*I was sick at heart to **see you attacked** earlier today.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22to+see+you+attacked%22) I'm not convinced it makes any difference to the meaning whether ***to be*** is an infinitive, continuous, or simply omitted.